# How do I create n nested loops from user Input n?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

The Problem I face is that I want to check how many diferent possibilities you have to get a certain sum out of n dices.
It should look like this:

```
n=numberOfDice
x=sum out of the rolled dice
counter=number of possibilities to get x out of n dice
```

I know - it's not the most efficient way to get the answer, but I want to try to create n nested loops out of a user input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would there be nested loops here? Please [edit] your question and give us an example of the loop. You're just showing three variable declarations, where does the _nested_ loop come in? And why would you have n nested loops?

Comment: You have an issue in your logic. `n` is the amount of times you need to run the loop rolling the dice, there is no need to nest loops here.

Comment: @Panki, nested loops are a simple way of generating all the permutations. (e.g. `for i in {1..6}; do for j in {1..6}; do echo $i,$j; done; done`). If you have a way to do it with just a loop going once for each die, then feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: this belongs to stackoverflow? maybe?

Comment: This is off topic as it has (what I can see) nothing inherently related to Unix or Linux. This is also non-trivial, but have been solved before, see e.g. https://practicallypredictable.com/2017/12/04/probability-distributions-dice-rolls/#sum-of-dice-rolls

Answer (score 0):

```
read -p 'dices=' ndices
read -p 'sum=' sum_cut
read -p 'repeat n=' rep

dices_sum ()
{
  dlist=''; sum=0
  local i
  for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++))
  do
    d=$(($RANDOM % 6 + 1))
    ((sum+=$d)); dlist+=$d
  done
}

count=0
for ((i=1; i<=$rep; i++))
do
  dices_sum $ndices
  echo "$sum ($dlist)"
  (($sum >= $sum_cut)) && ((count++))
done
echo "c/rep $count/$rep"
```

The outer loop is for the repetitions, the inner loop for each dice. I had to put `local i` in the function, otherwise the variable names collide.

call:

```
]# . dices.sh 
dices=3
sum=12
repeat n=10
7 (322)
8 (152)
8 (341)
11 (614)
14 (644)
17 (656)
5 (212)
15 (564)
8 (215)
10 (613)
c/rep 3/10
```

The function `dices_sum()` can be called by itself, with a positional parameter:

```
]# dices_sum 6
]# echo $dlist 
356123
```